# How to get multiple props simultaneously in React Native's Android Bridge UI component

Tags: android, react-native, google-api, google-pay, react-native-bridge

I'm trying to implement a React Native bridge between JS and Google Pay's [Android PayButton API](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/reference/client#PayButton), however I've come across a strange issue - I first need to know all React props in order to create the native PayButton View to return from my custom ViewManager.

Here's my `MyGooglePayButtonManager.java`:

```java
public class MyGooglePayButtonManager extends SimpleViewManager<PayButton> {
    public static final String REACT_CLASS = "GooglePayButton";
    ReactApplicationContext mCallerContext;

    public MyGooglePayButtonManager(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        mCallerContext = reactContext;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    @Override
    protected PayButton createViewInstance(@NonNull ThemedReactContext themedReactContext) {
        PayButton button = new PayButton(themedReactContext);
        button.initialize(
                ButtonOptions.newBuilder()
                        .setButtonTheme(ButtonConstants.ButtonTheme.DARK)
                        .setButtonType(ButtonConstants.ButtonType.BUY)
                        .setCornerRadius(100)
                        .setAllowedPaymentMethods("[]")
                        .build()
        );
        return button;
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "theme")
    public void setTheme(PayButton button, @NonNull int theme) {
        // button.setTheme(theme); -- DOESN'T WORK as Google doesn't allow changing of initialized PayButton.

        // Have to reinitialize the whole button instead. But I cannot know about other passed props unless
        // I store them in a local field and rebuild the button each time.
        button.initialize(ButtonOptions.newBuilder()
                .setButtonTheme(theme)
                .setButtonType(ButtonConstants.ButtonType.BUY)
                .setCornerRadius(100)
                .setAllowedPaymentMethods("[]")
                .build());
    }
}
```

The question is - can I somehow get all props of my component in `setTheme` method and only then initialize the PayButton?

One solution I can think of is passing props not separately but as one object prop, called sth like `buttonProps`, which would have `theme`, `cornerRadius` and other props. But it isn't ideal as usually React components have separate props.

Thanks!

EDIT: This is my current solution to achieve what I want. But I'm not sure if it isn't too expensive to re-initialize the button with each prop passed:

```java
public class MyGooglePayButtonManager extends SimpleViewManager<PayButton> {
    public static final String REACT_CLASS = "GooglePayButton";
    ReactApplicationContext mCallerContext;

    public MyGooglePayButtonManager(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        mCallerContext = reactContext;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    private int theme = ButtonConstants.ButtonTheme.DARK;
    private int type = ButtonConstants.ButtonType.BUY;
    private int cornerRadius = 20;

    @Override
    protected PayButton createViewInstance(@NonNull ThemedReactContext themedReactContext) {
        PayButton button = new PayButton(themedReactContext);
        buildButton(button);
        return button;
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "theme")
    public void setTheme(PayButton button, @NonNull int theme) {
        this.theme = theme;
        buildButton(button);
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "cornerRadius")
    public void setCornerRadius(PayButton button, @NonNull int cornerRadius) {
        this.cornerRadius = cornerRadius;
        buildButton(button);
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "type")
    public void setType(PayButton button, @NonNull int type) {
        this.type = type;
        buildButton(button);
    }

    private void buildButton(PayButton button) {
        button.initialize(ButtonOptions.newBuilder()
            .setButtonTheme(theme)
            .setButtonType(type)
            .setCornerRadius(cornerRadius)
            .setAllowedPaymentMethods("[]")
            .build());
    }
}
```